# Filtered KendoUI ComboBox in KnockoutJS foreach cycle

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I'm trying to create editable form where initial data are displayed and when user enters edit mode, Kendo ComboBoxes are displayed to select new values.

All values for combo boxes will be loaded on demand only when user starts edit mode (no need to fetch data to client just to view current state).

In other words - form is displayed as read only with inputs. Click on "edit" button. This will call service to load data (not in fiddle, just helper method) and displays ComboBoxes filtered by specific ID for every item in foreach cycle. So every ComboBox displays only proper values based on filter.

How to create working version of GetBrokersInRole() and bind it to form data?

Thnx

Markup:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Roles">
    <label data-bind="text: RoleName"></label>
    <div data-bind="visible: !$root.IsEditMode()">
        <input data-bind="enable: $root.IsEditMode(), value: ValueText" />
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: $root.IsEditMode()">
        <!-- OK -->
        <input data-bind="kendoComboBox: { data: $root.BrokersInRoles, dataTextField: 'BrokerName', dataValueField: 'BrokerID', value: ValueID }" />
        <!-- NOT OK -->
        <input data-bind="kendoComboBox: { data: $root.GetBrokersInRole($data), dataTextField: 'BrokerName', dataValueField: 'BrokerID', value: ValueID }" />
    </div>
</div>
<p>
    <button data-bind="click: StartEdit">Set Edit Mode</button>
</p>
<label data-bind="text: Brokers().length"></label>
```

ViewModel:

```
// Roles and initial values
var roles = [
    {"RoleID":1,"RoleName":"Role 1","ValueID":101,"ValueText":"Broker 1"},
    {"RoleID":2,"RoleName":"Role 2","ValueID":102,"ValueText":"Broker 2"},
    {"RoleID":3,"RoleName":"Role 3","ValueID":103,"ValueText":"Broker 3"},
    {"RoleID":4,"RoleName":"Role 4","ValueID":104,"ValueText":"Broker 4"}
];

// RolesID is collection of Roles where Broker is available
// so BrokerID=101 is available in ComboBox for RoleID 1 and 3
var brokers = [
    {"BrokerID":101,"BrokerName":"Broker 1","RolesID":"1;3"},
    {"BrokerID":102,"BrokerName":"Broker 2","RolesID":"1;2"},
    {"BrokerID":103,"BrokerName":"Broker 3","RolesID":"3"},
    {"BrokerID":104,"BrokerName":"Broker 4","RolesID":"4"}
];

// ViewModel
var ViewModel = function() {

    // Roles and initial values
    this.Roles = ko.observableArray(roles);
    // Initial value is empty - no comboboxes if not in edit mode (save data)
    this.BrokersInRoles = ko.observableArray([]);  
    // Is edit mode?
    this.IsEditMode = ko.observable(false);

    // Alternative method to AJAX load of Brokers collection
    // Until edit mode is active, BrokersInRoles collection is empty
    this.StartEdit = function() 
    { 
        var self = this;
        self.BrokersInRoles(brokers); // This will be AJAX load on demand
        self.IsEditMode(true); 
    };

    // Filter brokers based on role
    this.GetBrokersInRole = function (roleItem) {
        var self = this;

        var filtered = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.BrokersInRoles(), function (broker) {
            return _.contains(broker.RolesID().split(';'), roleItem.RoleTypeID().toString());
        });

        // Return only brokers in selected role
        return ko.observableArray(filtered);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/RaptorCZ/drkb6mLk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two things that can help fix this up. First, Knockout-Kendo is not set up to track dependencies on something that is not an observable or computed (like your function that returns values). So, it is not re-evaluated.

You could create a computed on each one of your `Roles` to represent that data or based on your code, you could wrap the `kendoComboBox` like:

```html
    <!-- ko with: $root.GetBrokersInRole($data) -->
    <input data-bind="kendoComboBox: { data: $data, dataTextField: 'BrokerName', dataValueField: 'BrokerID', value: $parent.ValueID }" />
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Now, it will be re-rendered properly, when dependencies accessed in `GetBrokersInRole` are updated.

Additionally, it looks like your filtering logic is slightly off (at least for the code in your fiddle). The properties on your roles are not observable and there wasn't a `RoleTypeID`. Perhaps this:

```js
var filtered = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.BrokersInRoles(), function (broker) {
       return _.contains(broker.RolesID.split(';'), roleItem.RoleID.toString());
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/kz5o5h5y/

Comment: Amazing, thnx for help. Yes, filtering function is little broken, because of copy&paste from real project to simplify problem.